# setWorldRotationFromEuler is creating issue in cocos creator 3.4

Tags: cocoscreator

I am trying to develop helix jump in Cocos creator 3.4 but I don't know how to make it smooth
When I try to use setWorldRotationFromEuler it moves the tower but when I click on same position it  moves back to initial touch pos.

```
  input.on(Input.EventType.TOUCH_MOVE
         , function(touch){    
  this.node.setWorldRotationFromEuler(0 ,touch.getLocationX()/2 ,0)           
    },this)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    input.on(Input.EventType.TOUCH_MOVE
        , function(touch){
   var qout1=Quat.toEuler(new Quat,this.tower.getRotation())
     this.node.setWorldRotationFromEuler(0,(qout1.y+touch.getDeltaX()/3),0)
   },this)
}
```

this will resolve the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).